# Separating Values in Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a variable that consists of multiple product skus and their respective quantities, like so:

```
$components = "SKUA,2,SKUB,2,SKUC,1,SKUD,2"
```

I can explode that and to get the array:

```
  $items = explode(";",$components);
    foreach($items as $item) {
      echo $item . '|';
      }
```

How would I go about performing a function against each item AND each quantity as long as they exist?

As an example, I want to check the SKU in Magento and see if the quantity listed in my array is available for each SKU listed:

The number of SKUs in the array will vary, and there will always be a quantity following each SKU.

Would a foreach actually work?

Comment: Smells like bad database design to me

Comment: What exactly do you mean, "check it against my database"? You just want to see if that SKU exists with that quantity? Are you trying to select something? Just guessing, you'd probably want to do something separate your SKUs and quantities into separate arrays, implode them with commas, and form some kind of query like `select * from mydb where SKU in ($SKUs)` or something like that.

Comment: Not out of the question. if I had to explain that part: Our inventory system doesn't recognize bundle items in Magento. Separating the items into separate line items while still keeping the bundle discount hasn't been solved. That being said, we're utilizing a simple item with an attribute that lists all of the contained skus in the bundle and the required quantities to determine the stock status that will be displayed.

Comment: I've edited the question to hopefully be a little bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about something like this:

```
$components = "SKUA,2,SKUB,2,SKUC,1,SKUD,2";
$split = explode(',', $components);

$Q = [];

for ($i=0; $i<count($split); $i+=2) {
  $sku = $split[$i]; $qty = $split[$i+1];
  $Q[]= "(SKU = '$sku' AND Qty >= $qty)";
}

$Query = 'select * from mydb where '.implode(' OR ', $Q);
```

That gives you a query like this:

```
select * from mydb where (SKU = 'SKUA' AND Qty >= 2) OR (SKU = 'SKUB' AND Qty >= 2) OR (SKU = 'SKUC' AND Qty >= 1) OR (SKU = 'SKUD' AND Qty >= 2)
```